# Загрузка txt в tstringgrid

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Как загрузить данные из текстового файла в стринггрид, так чтобы при встречи в txt табуляции данные переходили в новую ячейку. А также после загрузки записать данные ячеек в определённые поля записи?

Answer (score 1):

Следует прочитать описание свойств грида и о работе с TStrings, потом сделать что-то подобное:

```
Grid.Row[i].Delimiter := #9;
Grid.Row[i] := DelimitedText(Loaded_StringList[i]);
```